# ASP.NET MVC 4 Conditional Attributes and HTML Helpers

Tags: checkbox, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Can you do conditional attributes in a html helper like you would with a raw html element?

```
@Html.CheckBox("", new { @checked = (Model ? "checked" : null));
```

Not working for me, still renders a blanked "checked" attribute.  Would like it to work like the code below.

```
<div class="@myClass">Content</div>
```

Renders

```
<div>Content</div>
```

If @myClass is null

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this with a simple `@helper` method; something like:

```
@helper AwesomeCheckBox() {
  if (Model == null) {
    @Html.CheckBox("", new { @checked = null);
  } else {
    @Html.CheckBox("", new { @checked = "checked");
  }
}
```

Comment: If I have a ton of html attributes I would hate to duplicate all of them.

Comment: Hmm, you could use a hash or some other key/value pair (as a parameter) to handle that. Other than that, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the checkbox a name or it will throw an error and then the next attribute in line is the isChecked attribute so you just need to simply check if the Model is null or not like so.

```
@Html.CheckBox( "checkbox", Model == null )
```